# How to render view with specific viewmodel without using <compose>?

Tags: javascript, binding, aurelia

I have a `<dialog>` custom element and a `<fixed-bottom-dialog>` custom element whose viewmodel extends that of `<dialog>`. I want to render `<dialog>` within `<fixed-bottom-dialog>` using the current instance's viewmodel as the `<dialog>`'s viewmodel....

**dialog.ts**

```
import {inject, bindable} from "aurelia-framework";
import {DialogController} from "aurelia-dialog";

@inject(DialogController)
export class Dialog {
    public dialogClass: string;
    public dialogController: DialogController;

    constructor(dialogController: DialogController) {
        this.dialogController = dialogController;
    }
}
```

**dialog.html**

```
<template>
    <ai-dialog class="mdl-dialog ${dialogClass}">
        <ai-dialog-body class="mdl-dialog__content">
            <button mdl="button" class="mdl-button dialog-close-btn close" click.delegate="dialogController.cancel()">
                <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                <span>esc</span>
            </button>

            <slot></slot>
        </ai-dialog-body>
    </ai-dialog>
</template>
```

**fixed-bottom-dialog.ts**

```
import {Dialog} from "./dialog";

export class FixedBottomDialog extends Dialog {
    public dialogClass = "dialog-fixed-bottom";
}
```

**fixed-bottom-dialog.html**

```
<template>
    <require from="./dialog.html"></require>

    <dialog view-model.bind="this" containerless>
        <slot></slot>
    </dialog>
</template>
```

Hopefully this makes sense. I'm trying to pass the content all the way through to the final `<dialog>` custom element. Currently that part is working fine. The part that is not working is binding the current `FixedBottomDialog` viewmodel instance (`this`) to the `<dialog>` custom element for it to use as its own viewmodel. Is this even possible? I tried to use `<compose>` but it doesn't seem to pass the content of the element through.

Comment: try `<compose view-model.bind="$this" ....></compose>`. Just be careful because this is not a recommended approach

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Do you have insight into why it's not recommended?